VS 2022 Batch Build not considering platform when deciding build order
I have a C# project that I'm building both 32-bit and 64-bit dlls and (Wix) installers for, then including both MSIs in a Wix bundle. The Solution contains:

a C# dll
a 64-bit Wix installer
a 32-bit Wix installer
a 32-bit Wix bundle

I'm using the VS Batch Build, which should build in order:

Build the x64 C# dll (emitting xxx64.dll)
Build the x86 C# dll (emitting xxx32.dll)
Build the x64 Wix installer after #1 is done (using xxx64.dll, emitting xxx64.msi)
Build the x86 Wix installer after #2 is done (using xxx32.dll, emitting xxx32.msi)
Build the x86 Wix bundle after #3 and #4 are done (using xxx64.msi and xxx32.msi, emitting setup.exe)

I have Project dependencies set up between the two Wix installer projects and the c# dll project (and the bundle depending on the two installer projects). When I run it as a batch build of all those components in one go, I find that both the Wix installer projects are kicked off as soon as the x64 dll is built, so the 32-bit installer picks up the previous build of the 32-bit dll.
How can I control the build order / project dependencies so they consider the target platform as well as the project hierarchy?

Just being nosey, is there a specific reason you’re building for x86?  Unless working with a legacy system; the vast majority of modern systems run 64bit.  Seems like unnecessary overhead.

Yes, the dll is an Office COM Addin; there's lots of people still running both 32- and 64- bit Office.
